downloaded file instead of load the app express vercel
I deployed in vercel for my express application. What appears on the dashboard is only a white page, and when pressed, it immediately downloads my server.ts file.
blank dashboard
build log looks good without error.
vercel settings:
vercel settings
Here is my folder structure:
folder structure
my vercel.json:
{
    "version": 2,
    "rewrites": [     
        {       
            "source": "/(.*)",       
            "destination": "/src/server.ts"     
        }   
    ] 
}

my scripts at package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "vercel-build": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node-dev --respawn src/index.ts",
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "ts.check": "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js",
    "build:prod": "pnpm prisma:generate && pnpm build",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "env:check": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production ts-node scripts/checkEnv.ts",
    "migrate:dev": "prisma migrate dev",
    "migrate:dev:create": "prisma migrate dev --create-only",
    "migrate:dev:reset": "prisma migrate reset",
    "migrate:prod": "dotenv -e .env.prod -- prisma migrate deploy",
    "migrate:prod:status": "dotenv -e .env.prod -- prisma migrate status",
    "migrate:prod:reset": "dotenv -e .env.prod -- prisma migrate reset",
    "db:seed:dev": "prisma db seed",
    "db:seed:prod": "dotenv -e .env.prod -- prisma db seed",
    "prisma:studio:prod": "dotenv -e .env.prod -- prisma studio",
    "prisma:generate:prod": "dotenv -e .env.prod -- prisma generate",
    "prisma:studio": "prisma studio",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate",
    "prisma:format": "prisma format"
  },

If more information is needed, please let me know, I'll update my question. Thank you.
I followed some recommendations I found on the internet and they said everything should work. Maybe there are some settings I missed. What could it be?
